# RPI-Imager Unable to Download OS List

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi-imager

I've downloaded the Raspberry Pi Imager for Ubuntu and attempted to run it with `rpi-imager`. This gives the folllowing output:

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get1_peer_certificate
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_PKEY_get_base_id
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_load_verify_dir
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_load_verify_dir
qt.network.ssl: An error encountered while to set root certificates location: ""
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_get1_peer_certificate
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_get1_peer_certificate
Unrecognised QT error:  QNetworkReply::SslHandshakeFailedError , explainer:  "SSL handshake failed"
```

The application then launches and displays a pop-up saying "Unable to download OS list". How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: It is likely that the lack of response to your question is because the problem is in an unknown system where you are trying to run the imager.  You might search for a list of Ubuntu packages that need to be installed before running imager.  Also, update your system to the current Ubuntu release (if you're running Ubuntu) and apply updates.